# Query feeditem object with InsertedById.name

Tags: apex, visualforce, query, feeditem

I am trying to run the following query

```
relatedFeedItems = [select Body, CreatedDate, createdby.name, 
                           InsertedById.name, SystemModstamp
                    from FeedItem]
```

Here the **`InsertedById.name`** is throwing an error. However just **`InsertedById`** is working. Can anyone tell me if it would be possible to query feeditem with the **`InsertedById.name`** in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
relatedFeedItems = [select Body, CreatedDate, createdby.name, 
                               InsertedBy.name, SystemModstamp
                        from FeedItem]
```

`InsertedById` provides id so you can not access fields with that.You need to replace that with `InsertedBy`.